# Using APEX to create a CRUD application

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to create an application that allows the user to enter enter details about a landmark. The should be able to enter the name, upload an image, type, description, postcode & location data.

I need to use ORDSYS.ORDImage & MYSYS.SDO_Geometry data types. In APEX there is a "?" next to columns that use these datatypes.

How do I display the contents of these datatypes in APEX ?

Thank You.

The Apex Application

[image]

Problem Adding a Record

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apex doesn't support these datatypes out of the box. They have no display types.

You'd best go about it by creating a package with a procedure to fetch the data, and one to process the data.
You can handle the ordsys image as a blob, so it can be handled with a filebrowse/display image item. The file will have to go to the apex_application_temp_files table on submit, and you'll have to move it over from there to your table.
For the geometry object, you could fetch its data into several fields, and on submit collate it all together again in an object and performing the dml statements with it.

Comment: Thank you for that. I am fairly new to this so could you explain how I would go about this please?